Contract Negotiation: For personal financial safety, is it better to negotiate a longer notice period or not?
This question might be weird but I've been thinking about it; say I have a new contract and I could hypothetically choose between:

No notice
2 weeks
1 month
2+ months

What would it be in my best interest? I understand that a shorter notice period allows me to quit a toxic environment or jump onto a new opportunity quickly.
But, on the other hand, a longer notice period might help me softening the blow of an unexpected lay off (common these days).
I was thinking and 2 months seemed reasonable to me, as it is not too long to lose a possible incredible opportunity while also having 2 months of wages almost surely guaranteed.
Is that a good reasoning? If not, why?

No one can answer that for you, it will depend on a whole bunch of personal factors

@mattfreake This is a discussion not a decision for myself. I only see people recommending for shorter notice periods without weighing the alternatives, so having a generic conversation around it could be useful to people having a similar question.

Discussion is not what Stack Exchange is about. Questions of opinion are explicitly out of bounds, as are personal decisions. If you ask what the trade-offs might be, that would be in scope.

VTC - We cannot answer. Ultimately, it is dependent on you and your personal factors (which we do not know).

Opinion: If your primary concern is safety, longer is better. But that gives up some flexibility. Note that I've actually never seen this be a negotiable point, and personally I'd consider it a lower priority than other concerns.

Unanswerable without a location.  In the US a 2 week period is customary and acceptable, contracts are not, and there is nothing to say that employer has to honor the notice period in the case of a layoff.


What would it be in my best interest? I understand that a shorter
notice period allows me to quit a toxic environment or jump onto a new
opportunity quickly.

When you are quitting you want the shortest notice period possible. You have to also know if they are obligated to keep you employed, or can they write you a check for the notice period, or if they can terminate your employment immediately with no additional pay. Some of this depends on the location. It also helps to know about vacation hours and benefits such as insurance.
When they are letting you go you due to financial reasons you want as long of a notice as possible, but more so you need to know if there is any severance money. Again understanding vacation and benefits is important.
If they are firing you for performance, they generally want you gone quickly. Severance and benefits are the most important thing.
In some cases these periods aren't the same. In other cases they are the same. It can also depend on how long you have worked there. During a probationary period, these notice periods are very short.
The advantage of a short notice period when you are quitting is that the uncomfortable part is short. You also have maximum flexibility. If the new job offer has conditions, then you can wait until all of them are met and then give two weeks notice. The tougher thing is to have to wait for the complex background check to be completed, and then have to give 90 days notice.

Isn't the severance money the bit where they pay you X to stay at home instead of doing the whole notice period at the job? Could it happen that the contract states a notice period of X and the company just wants you out without neither severance money nor letting you work? Would that be legal?

No. Severance payments are a loyalty bonus. Amounts are affected by how long you have been with the company. Details vary, so you'll have to look at your own contract and your own company's policies for details. In my case, after almost 4 decades with the firm, severance was on the order of $30k, so this can be significant. Note that severance payments are often tied to an exit agreement, usually a promise that you will not try to sue the company for firing you and things like that, so when they become relevant you need to decide whether they are offering enough to be worth signing.

I have never had a contract mentioning severance, so I wouldn't even know how they would look like. Do they have a formula like: severance = Years * 1k or something?

@keshlam in the UK severance pay is often legally required; and the company cannot ask you to do anything in return. Companies will often offer a higher severance pay for signing a deal like you can’t sue them, NDA etc. Which is absolutely legal since you can insist on getting the lower legal severance pay only. Often has tax advantages as well due to some intricacies of UK tax law.

@gnasher: Ah. Base plus operational enhanced.   In the US base is zero.

@N3SH:: Since in the US it's a matter of contract, details vary. Often, as with retirement benefits, there's some minimum time of service before one qualifies for this benefit; after that it may be linear accrual or some number of weeks of salary or something in that range

Generally your best choice is to choose what's "normal" in your local environment.  For example in the US the "normal" is two weeks (and even that is mostly optional).
With a 2 month notice period, you may have difficulties finding a new job since most employers will expect that you can start 2-3 weeks after the offer has issued. Of course you can try to negotiate a later start date but that gives you a distinct disadvantage against competing candidates how don't have that constraint.

Good point of view I hadn't thought about

Very important point. So “best length”  in USA and “best length” in UK will be different.
